# nginx rewrite to index.php?q=$uri

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-location

I have to update a nginx host so all requests to an alias are rewritten to `/alias_path/index.php?q=$uri`. But now all the assets are no longer available.

This is my current configuration. And I'm getting closer, but when I am uncommenting the last location, the assets are no longer available.

```
    location /csv-import {
            alias /var/www/csv-import/public;

            location ~ \.php$ {
                    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME        $request_filename;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            }

            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

            #location ~ ^/csv-import/(.*)$ {
                    #alias /var/www/csv-import/public;
                    #try_files $uri $uri/ /csv-import/index.php?q=$1;
            #}

            error_log /var/log/nginx/csv-import.error.log;
            access_log /var/log/nginx/csv-import.access.log;
    }
```

The file I wan't to reach is `/var/www/csv-import/public/index.php`. All Urls like `example.com/csv-import/some/url` should be rewritten to `example.com/csv-import/index.php?q=some/url` but assets like `example.com/csv-import/css/app.css` should be available under `/var/www/csv-import/public/css/app.css`.

I'm shure there is a solution that works perfect but I couldn't come up with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need another `location` block. The usual method is to change the default action of the `try_files` statement. But because of [this issue](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97), an `if` block may be simpler:

```
location ^~ /csv-import {
    alias /var/www/csv-import/public;

    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/csv-import/(.*)$ /csv-import/index.php?q=$1 last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        ...
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/csv-import.error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/csv-import.access.log;
}
```

The `if` block replaces the `try_files` statement. The `^~` operator avoids any ambiguity with other [`location`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) blocks. See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.